# ssis script task corrupts excel 2010 file

Tags: excel, ssis, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to format an Excel 2010 doc and the file creates fine and the data is there, but when the script task goes to format the file it gets corrupted. I have also noticed that it will only read the first of 2 worksheets. Here is the code:

```
    Dim lintLastRow As Integer
    Dim lstrLastCol, lstrHeader As String
    Dim mobjWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim mappExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim lobjWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim emptyBytes(0) As Byte
    Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

    Try
        mappExcel.Visible = False
        mappExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
        mappExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        mappExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
        mobjWorkbook = mappExcel.Workbooks.Open(Dts.Variables("FilePath").Value + Dts.Variables("FileName").Value)
        mobjWorkbook.RefreshAll()
        Dts.Log("worksheet count: " & mobjWorkbook.Sheets.Count, 0, emptyBytes)
        For Each lobjWorksheet In mobjWorkbook.Sheets
            If lobjWorksheet.Name = "Compare" Then
                lstrLastCol = "T"
                lstrHeader = "- Compare Results"
            Else
                lstrLastCol = "H"
                lstrHeader = "- Trans UnMatch"
            End If
            'Dts.Log("Set worksheet: " & lintCount, 0, emptyBytes)
            'lobjWorksheet = mobjWorkbook.Sheets.Item(lintCount)
            Dts.Log("worksheet select", 0, emptyBytes)
            lobjWorksheet.Select()
            lobjWorksheet.Range("A1").Select()
            If lobjWorksheet.Cells(2, 1).value = Nothing Then
                lintLastRow = 4
            Else
                lobjWorksheet.Application.Cells.End(XlDirection.xlDown).Select()
                lintLastRow = lobjWorksheet.Application.ActiveCell.Row + 2
            End If
            Dts.Log("last row: " & lintLastRow, 0, emptyBytes)
            lobjWorksheet.Rows(1).Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, False)
            lobjWorksheet.Rows(1).Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, False)
            lobjWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).value = "PAM - GL Portfolio Level " + lstrHeader + " for " + Today
            lobjWorksheet.Range("A1", lstrLastCol + "1").Merge()
            lobjWorksheet.Range("A1").RowHeight = 27
            lobjWorksheet.Range("A1", lstrLastCol + "3").Font.Bold = True
            lobjWorksheet.Range("C4", lstrLastCol & lintLastRow).NumberFormat = "0.00" ' = FormatNumber("#####.00").
            lobjWorksheet.Range("A3", lstrLastCol & lintLastRow).EntireColumn.AutoFit()
            lobjWorksheet.Range("A1", lstrLastCol & lintLastRow).Font.Name = "Arial"
            lobjWorksheet.Range("A1").Select()
            Dts.Log("Complete Update", 0, emptyBytes)
        Next

        mobjWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Select()
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Format Excel Failed: ", _
        ex.Message & ControlChars.CrLf & ex.StackTrace, _
        String.Empty, 0)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    Finally
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
        mobjWorkbook.Save()
        mobjWorkbook.Close()
        ReleaseCom(lobjWorksheet)
        ReleaseCom(mobjWorkbook)
        mappExcel.Quit()
        ReleaseCom(mappExcel)
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    End Try
```

This works fine on my machine and a pilot environment. When it goes to production things go downhill quick. Any thoughts on what I am missing would be great.

Thanks

Comment: In what way is it corrupted - do you have an error? Did you open it before the macro to verify that it is the macro and not a prior step? It can be enlightening to rename the extension to .ZIP and extract the XML and compare a corrupted and non corrupted file, in all four cases (before and after in dev and prod)

Comment: I did open the file before the script and it looks fine. I do have an issue where the script errors trying to get to the second sheet (index error and there are only two sheets). If the script saves the workbook, then the file is corrupt. If not, then I can open the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converter was installed and must have needed a reboot because the server was rebooted this weekend and everything seems to be working. So I think we are good now.

Answer (score 0):

So the original issue I believe was caused by the Excel converter not being installed on the server. Once that was install, I started to get the following error:

```
OnError,PGIDSMSQL045,PRINCIPALUSA\TWSPGIAC,Formate Excel,{610A1615-E16E-4B62-8A93-F692A478FCF9},{EF8F3734-6467-423C-A9D3-BF2463EEFD44},04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,0,0x,The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)) at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
   at ST_0391e3bc80224a34819c14be208559c5.vbproj.ScriptMain.Main()
OnError,PGIDSMSQL045,PRINCIPALUSA\TWSPGIAC,PAM-GLPortLvlRecon,{008D2838-612E-4DBB-AEE7-65145ED0BAAC},{EF8F3734-6467-423C-A9D3-BF2463EEFD44},04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,0,0x,The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
   at ST_0391e3bc80224a34819c14be208559c5.vbproj.ScriptMain.Main()
OnError,PGIDSMSQL045,PRINCIPALUSA\TWSPGIAC,Formate Excel,{610A1615-E16E-4B62-8A93-F692A478FCF9},{EF8F3734-6467-423C-A9D3-BF2463EEFD44},04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,8,0x,The script returned a failure result.
OnError,PGIDSMSQL045,PRINCIPALUSA\TWSPGIAC,PAM-GLPortLvlRecon,{008D2838-612E-4DBB-AEE7-65145ED0BAAC},{EF8F3734-6467-423C-A9D3-BF2463EEFD44},04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,8,0x,The script returned a failure result.
OnError,PGIDSMSQL045,PRINCIPALUSA\TWSPGIAC,Formate Excel,{610A1615-E16E-4B62-8A93-F692A478FCF9},{EF8F3734-6467-423C-A9D3-BF2463EEFD44},04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,1,0x,System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ST_0391e3bc80224a34819c14be208559c5.vbproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
OnError,PGIDSMSQL045,PRINCIPALUSA\TWSPGIAC,PAM-GLPortLvlRecon,{008D2838-612E-4DBB-AEE7-65145ED0BAAC},{EF8F3734-6467-423C-A9D3-BF2463EEFD44},04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,04/18/2013 11:52:09 AM,1,0x,System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ST_0391e3bc80224a34819c14be208559c5.vbproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

This has been more fun then I ever wanted...but a good challange. 
I have check the variables and they have the correct information. The user has full access to the output directory because it creates the file in earlier steps. So I am not sure what I am missing. Note: This whole process works when it was formatting an .xls file so I am not sure what is going on with .xlsx.
thanks

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.. probably means you have the same issue - it's trying to find the third sheet and can't find it. So by corrupt you mean you try and open the file and it says something ilke 'I am corrupt'? Whats the exact error message?

Comment: It was an Excel error (Sorry, I don't have the exact error) that the file was corrupt and could not be opened. I was not seeing the converter that was just installed.